# mongodb - connecting to test for so long

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to Mongo DB. I'm trying to install MongoDB in my laptop by following [this tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/). I followed the command in the tutorial to start the MongoDb and to connect. When i start to connect  `C:\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe` 
it prompt new CMD and it saying connecting to:test, but it remain same for so long. Appreciate  if some could advice on this.

***ScreenShot***
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that there is no error. This is the javascript shell screen.You can use [shell commands](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/javascript/) on that screen. You can find the shell reference [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/dbshell+Reference).

Comment: What the different using javascript shell screen and shell commands.?

Comment: You can use shell commands on the shell screen to make operations such as insert,update,find,delete and etc. on your contents. You can also do this operations using mongo drivers.

Comment: I haven't reach that part yet. I don't know whether my db connected since it show connecting for so long.

Comment: can you type any command on shell? what you see when you type help on the shell?

Comment: im using windows command prompt. When i type help it show list of help name.

Comment: AT this point, you are NOT in the windows shell.  You are in the mongodb shell and you can interact with mongodb there.  For a tutorial, I highly suggest you go here: http://www.mongodb.org/ and click the "Try It Out" link at the top.  I think you'll find it matches exactly what you are doing here.

Answer (score 2):

As of MongoDB 2.2rc0, there are some clearer instructions displayed the first time you start the `mongo` shell.

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.0-rc0
connecting to: test
Welcome to the MongoDB shell.
For interactive help, type "help".
For more comprehensive documentation, see
    http://docs.mongodb.org/
Questions? Try the support group
    http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user
>
```